# Treeview ContextMenu with no Click Event Handler in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview, contextmenu

I have a TreeView, and I want to be able to add children to it and to the Linq to SQL database that it's bound to.

The best way that I can think of (off the top of my head) would be to have the user right click on a parent node and have the option to add new item from a context menu.

I added a context menu, but when I try to program it in the back end, it says that there is no event handler associated with it.

```
        <TreeView Name="TreeView1" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ManufacturerWarranty, Path=ManufacturerQuery, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WarrantyList}">
                    <TextBlock Name="txtManufacturerName" Text="{Binding Path=ManufacturerName}">
                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Name="mnuAddRecord" Header="Add Year Record"></MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Years}">
                                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Name="mnuDelRecord" Header="Remove Year Record"></MenuItem>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

Whats the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `add handler` which will execute on `click of menuItem`

```
<ContextMenu>
  <MenuItem Name="mnuAddRecord" Header="Add Year Record" Click="HandlerInClass"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: When I first had the context menu as part of the treeview itself I was able to do the handler in the code behind `sub mnuAddRecord_Click(...) handles mnuAddRecord.click`. I also tried adding the handler the way you suggest, but was having trouble getting the record information for the originating node. I'll look into it more.